# collecting item game

Tags: game-engine

I want to make a game that can collecting item.I want to make a system like when we press "E" when we are nearby the door to go to the next level,it will check how many items that we have.If it is lower than (let say) seven,the door will locked.but,if it is higher than 7,the door will open

Comment: you can do this, even with logic notes. A property could be used to count... But how far is your game? And what exactly is your question?

Comment: @mr car your question is not understood, can you edit or put an image of what you want to do ???